# Invoice Increment ID adjustment for API in Magento 2

Tags: rest-api, magento2.3.3, sales-invoice, magento2.3.x

I would like to change the `increment_id` for invoices. I tried this by running the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE sequence_invoice_1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 504;
```

This works for the invoice id but it does not work when working through the rest API because the API uses the `entity_id` column from `sales_order` table. For some bookkeeping implementation I need to change the `entity_id` above 500 through the rest API.

How to accomplish to change the value for the next `entity_id`?

Comment: Default Frontend store id is 1. if you have multi-store then you have to set query for each store with table name like sequence_order_2 up to sequence_order_.*

Comment: @Kushal, yes I know but that isn't the case here. Store id 1 is the correct one. The problem is the entity_id which is not updated but is used by the rest API.